# How to setup alert in helm chart values file?

Tags: grafana, helm

I am trying to setup grafana alerts in helm chart.

For that, using the existing manually created alert from another grafana instance, which we want to keep in new grafana setup by default with helm chart.

As not able to find any export/import option, trying to edit manually.
In this sample: helm-charts/values.yaml at main · grafana/helm-charts (github.com)

Found the alerts option in the values file [link](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L524)/ But not able to set below attributes

But, not able to find below option in the values file to set.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Please help.
And also where to get datasourceUid and orgId values to set in alerts?

sample rule in chart:

```
alerting:
  rules.yaml:
    apiVersion: 1
    groups:
      - orgId: 1
        folder: "Performance Metrics"
        name: qtm
        interval: 60s
        rules:
          - uid: my_id_1
            condition: B
            title: qtm
            data:
              - refId: A
                queryType: ""
                relativeTimeRange:
                  from: 600
                  to: 0
                datasourceUid: "-100"
                model:
                  editorMode: code
                  expr: '100 * (sum(rate(n_bolt_api_usage{app="data-cruncher-read-replica", err="internal"}[60m])) or vector(0)) / (vector(1) or  (sum(rate(n_bolt_api_usage{app="data-cruncher-read-replica"}[60m]))))'
                  hide: false
                  intervalMs: 1000
                  legendFormat: __auto
                  maxDataPoints: 43200
                  range: true
                  refId: A
              - refId: B
                queryType: ""
                relativeTimeRange:
                  from: 0
                  to: 0
                datasourceUid: "-100"
                model:
                  conditions:
                    - evaluator:
                        params:
                          - 10
                        type: gt
                      operator:
                        type: and
                      query:
                        params:
                          - A
                      reducer:
                        params: []
                        type: last
                      type: query
                  datasource:
                    type: __expr__
                    uid: "-100"
                  expression: A
                  hide: false
                  intervalMs: 1000
                  maxDataPoints: 43200
                  refId: B
                  type: classic_conditions
            updated: "2022-09-22T18:27:51Z"
            noDataState: NoData
            execErrState: Alerting
            for: 1h
            annotations:
              summary: P1 QTM  High Internal Errors in API Usage
```

Getting error as:

> logger=ngalert uid=my_id_1 org=1 version=4 attempt=0
> now=2022-09-23T15:52:00Z t=2022-09-23T15:52:00.001235843Z level=error
> msg="failed to evaluate alert rule" results="[{Instance: State:Error
> Error:failed to execute conditions: invalid expression command type in
> 'A' EvaluatedAt:2022-09-23 15:52:00 +0000 UTC
> EvaluationDuration:1.232689ms EvaluationString: Values:map[]}]"
> duration=92.684µs

Comment: You appear to be missing a `|` from the end of the end of the `rules.yaml: ` line. It should be `rules.yaml: |` (I have edited the answer, the example I took it from was also missing it)

Comment: In the final configmap generated, that is there as you mentioned. The syntax above is same as mentioned in the grafana repo link, https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L524

Answer (score 1):

This a new feature in one of the latest release (9.1.x iirc)

And is discussed in the docs here https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#alerting

Which can be included in the gafana values file as follows:

e.g.

```yaml
alerting:
  rules.yaml: |
    apiVersion: 1
    groups:
    ....
  contactpoints.yaml: |
    apiVersion: 1
    contactPoints:
    ....
```

See PR https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/pull/1720 for details.

The `orgId` and `datasourceUid` you should already have from when you provisioned them earlier in your `values.yaml` (https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#data-sources)

As for how to get hold of the Alert query section, I think it's implied that you have to manually build it in the Web UI then extract it via the API (https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/alerting_provisioning/#route-get-alert-rule)

```
        condition: A
        # <list, required> list of query objects that should be executed on each
        #                  evaluation - should be obtained trough the API
       data:
       ...
```

Comment: how to set the query above in the values file, can you show that attribute related to that?

Comment: It's laid out in this PR https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/pull/1720 and there should be a commented out example in the new values.yaml file

Comment: I am able to setup contact points and some configuration to alerts as mentioned already, if you see the first screenshot shared, where I highlighted metrics browser part, can you tell how to set that value atlease

Comment: Your edit should have been a comment. New alert rules created in the UI will not be written to the filesystem, as I mentioned, you will have to use the HTTP API (docs link in answer) to get the `data` section to go in the values file.

Comment: I created an api key with admin role and ran like (  curl -H "Authorization: Bearer tokencreated" http://34.70.85.144/api/v1/provisioning/alert-rules  ). But getting error as {"message": "Not Found"}  Any suggestion, how to export the alert rule

Comment: You need to include a Alert UID on the end of that URL (you can't just list them all by the look of the doc). You can find the UID in the web UI URL when editing the Alert

Comment: Able to export the json file of alert using this.
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer tokenvalue" http://34.70.85.144/api/v1/provisioning/alert-rules/GIW56LnVz

But, can you suggest how to import this?

Comment: JSON is valid YAML... but I'd probably re-type it as YAML so it's easier to read.

Comment: I tried using json to yaml online converters and kept as part of helm chart values file, that is not loading properly. To simiplify, thought to use the POST /api/v1/provisioning/alert-rules, but not creating, it would be helpful if you provide such sampel for that

Comment: I added the sample chart and error coming with that from the data taken from exported curl command